# Why are dummy objects created in twisted's pb system?

Tags: python, twisted, perspective-broker

As shown below, in `twisted.spread.flavors.RemoteCache.unjellyFor`, we create a dummy object called `cProxy` and return it to the rest of the client code, rather than returning `self`.

```
def unjellyFor(self, unjellier, jellyList):
    if unjellier.invoker is None:
        return setInstanceState(self, unjellier, jellyList)
    self.broker = unjellier.invoker
    self.luid = jellyList[1]
    cProxy = _newDummyLike(self)
    # XXX questionable whether this was a good design idea...
    init = getattr(cProxy, "__init__", None)
    if init:
        init()
    unjellier.invoker.cacheLocally(jellyList[1], self)
    cProxy.setCopyableState(unjellier.unjelly(jellyList[2]))
    # Might have changed due to setCopyableState method; we'll assume that
    # it's bad form to do so afterwards.
    self.__dict__ = cProxy.__dict__
    # chomp, chomp -- some existing code uses "self.__dict__ =", some uses
    # "__dict__.update".  This is here in order to handle both cases.
    self.broker = unjellier.invoker
    self.luid = jellyList[1]
    return cProxy
```

The body of _newDummyLike looks like this:

```
def _newDummyLike(instance):
    """
    Create a new instance like C{instance}.

    The new instance has the same class and instance dictionary as the given
    instance.

    @return: The new instance.
    """
    if isinstance(instance.__class__, type):
        # New-style class
        dummy = _DummyNewStyle()
    else:
        # Classic class
        dummy = _Dummy()
    dummy.__class__ = instance.__class__
    dummy.__dict__ = instance.__dict__
    return dummy
```

Since the dummy object `cProxy` shares its `__dict__` and `__class__` with the "real" object, I don't see the point of making the dummy at all. Why is the dummy created?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of these "dummy" objects is distributed garbage collection.

First, let's consider the simple case of a `Copyable`.  Each time you serialize it, your peer gets a new `RemoteCopy`.  Simple - nothing to keep track of.  Your `Copyable` can be easily garbage collected at any time.

Next, `Referenceable`.  Every time you serialize it, your peer gets a new `RemoteReference`.  Now we have a problem: if your peers still have that `RemoteReference`, they should be able to call methods on your `Referenceable`, which means your broker now holds a strong reference to your `Referenceable`.  Slightly trickier, but still fairly simple: each time a `RemoteReference` is garbage collected, in `RemoteReference.__del__`, we send a `decref` message which tells the sender that their `Referenceable` is no longer referenced.  When the count gets to zero, the strong reference may be eliminated, and it will be garbage collected naturally.  This works because a `RemoteReference` is effectively immutable - all it contains is the opaque identifier of the object in question, a reference to the broker, and nothing else.

Finally, `Cacheable`.  Here we run into a real conundrum.  You serialize your `Cacheable`, and now the `Broker` needs to maintain a strong reference to the `Cacheable`, in order to be able to tell whether it's the same `Cacheable` being sent again, later.  But on the other end of the wire, the `RemoteCache` - which needs to have a `__del__` that informs us if the implicit reference to the `Cacheable` is going away - also has a strong reference from *its* broker, because the `Cacheable` may need to send updates to the `RemoteCache`.

This is a circular reference, and a bad one.  We need some way to break the circularity so that the thing we hand to the application, which gets garbage collected, tracks each time the server sent us a different copy of the `RemoteCache`.  It turns out that we *can* do that, and break the circular reference (remember, this code predates python's GC!) by haivng a separate instance object, each with its own `__del__` method, for each `RemoteCache` sent across.  But we can preserve the *illusion* of consistency by giving the application objects which share their internal state (`__dict__`), without letting objects with a `__del__` become uncollectable by letting them participate in a cycle.  This way, when `RemoteCache` objects get garbage collected, they each send a message, and we leave the "real" one (`self` in your example) with the strong reference from the broker, it becomes the "zeroeth" reference, which is why it's copied the first time as well (you can see there's only one other call site for `_newDummyLike` which is where repeat references to the same cacheable are deserialized - getting a new proxy object each time).

Hopefully this makes more sense!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a trick to make the necessary object.  Creating a new instance of a totally arbitrary, user-defined type is harder.  What arguments do you pass to its `__init__`?  What if it's `__init__` has undesirable side-effects?  Maybe you can use its `__new__` method instead - but what arguments does that take?  Or maybe it doesn't even have a `__new__` method, or maybe `__new__` has side-effects... etc.

Compared to figuring all of that out, which may not even be possible, this trick is pretty simple and straight-forward.

Comment: The cProxy's `__init__` is identical to the user-provided `__init__` by construction (they share the same `__dict__`), and is called with no arguments, so I don't understand your answer. The reason I'm asking about this is that this two-object strategy has the undesirable effect that if I call `id(self)` within an `observe_*` method I get a different result than if I call `id(myRemoteCacheInstance)` anywhere else, or call `id(self)` within a non `observe_*` method. This is pretty clearly a bug and I'd like to fix it once someone like you helps me understand why things are the way they are.

Comment: I think these dummy objects are unrelated to the two object issue you've encountered.  The dummy objects are a way to get *any* instance at all.  The fact that sometimes there seem to be two instances representing the same thing is separate - the code could just as easily only ever create a single dummy instance.

Comment: Also note that `__init__` is not in the instance `__dict__`.  It comes from the class object.

Comment: It sounds like the real question here is "why does `RemoteCache` copy itself"?